# GOLang - Verificação de Dependências

Tags: golang

Preciso alterar o response do get abaixo:

```
    router.GET("/health", func(context *gin.Context) {
    context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "message": "OK",
    })
})
```

Preciso criar um verificador de dependências. A request deve seguir o seguinte modelo:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "Nenhum problema encontrado",
    "dependencies": [
        {
            "name": "DEPENDENCIA",
            "status": "OK",
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é o problema, tente descrever melhor aonde você quer chegar.

Comment: Daniel, você precisa criar uma `struct` com os campos que você quer, popular eles com as informações e retornar como JSON

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, tem duas formas de se fazer isso.

**Solução 1**

Criar uma estrutura com tudo o que precisa ser transportado, facilitando inclusive manusear a informação por dentro do sistema.

```
type Control struct {
    Status string
    Message string
    Dependencies []Dependency
}

type Dependency struct {
    Name string
    Status string
}

myVar := Control{
    Status: "OK",
    Message: "Nenhum problema encontrado",
    Dependencies: [
        Dependency{
            Name: "DEPENDENCIA",
            Status: "OK",
        }
    ]
}
```

Solução 2

```
context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
    "status": "OK",
    "message": "Nenhum problema encontrado",
    "dependencies": gin.H{
        "name": "DEPENDENCIA",
        "status": "OK",
    }
})
```